# There's something in the 'conexaoHttp' método that's not working

Tags: java, playframework, request, connection, httpclient

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Redirect;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import models.Aparelho;
import models.Status;
import play.data.validation.Valid;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.With;
import security.Seguranca;

public class Aparelhos extends Controller {

    public static void form(Aparelho aparelho) {
        render(aparelho);
    }

    public static void menu() {
        render();
    }

    public static void salvar(@Valid Aparelho aparelho) {
        long qtd = Aparelho.count("nome = ?1 and id <> ?2", aparelho.nome, aparelho.id);
        if (validation.hasErrors()) {
            validation.keep();
            form(aparelho);
        }

        if (qtd == 0) {
            aparelho.status = Status.desligado;
            aparelho.save();
            flash.success("Cadastro realizado com sucesso.");
        } else {
            flash.error("O aparelho informado já possui cadastro.");
        }
        listar();
    }

    public static void listar() {
        String termo = params.get("termo");

        List<Aparelho> aparelhos = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        if (termo == null || termo.isEmpty()) {
            aparelhos = Aparelho.findAll();
        } else {
            aparelhos = Aparelho.find(
                    "(lower(nome) like ?1 OR lower(enderecoIp) like ?2 "
                            + " OR lower(enderecoMac) like ?3 OR lower(local) like ?4)",
                    "%" + termo.toLowerCase() + "%", "%" + termo.toLowerCase() + "%", "%" + termo.toLowerCase() + "%",
                    "%" + termo.toLowerCase() + "%").fetch();
        }
        render(aparelhos, termo);
    }

    public static void funcionar(Long id) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Aparelho ap = Aparelho.findById(id);
        String ip = ap.enderecoIp;
        String cod;

        if (ap.status == Status.ligado) {
            cod = ap.codIrDesligar;
            conexaoHttp(ip, cod);
            ap.status = Status.desligado;
        } else {
            cod = ap.codIrLigar;
            conexaoHttp(ip, cod);
            ap.status = Status.ligado;
        }

        ligados();
    }

    public static void conexaoHttp(String ip, String cod) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"ip address\": \"" + ip + "\", \"codigo\": \" " + cod + "\"}"))
                .uri(URI.create("")).headers("Accept", "application/json")

                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL).build();

        httpClient.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()).thenApply(HttpResponse::body);
    }
```

The message that appears is:
The file /app/controllers/Aparelhos.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : java.net.http.HttpClient cannot be resolved

It's my first time trying to make an http connection with java. I'm using play! Framework

In this case, what I want to happen is for the 'conexaoHttp' method to send to the url that I put only an ip address and a code that are registered in my database.

Comment: Are you using a java 11 or higher compiler?

Comment: I´m using a java 18